# Specializing class template member function based on type requirement in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization, enable-if

Given a class template of:

```
template<typename T>
class AAA
    {
    void XXX(T val) { /* code */ }
    void YYY(T val) { /* code */ }
    };
```

I know I can specialize the member function XXX for a particular type such as an 'int' with:

```
template<> void AAA<int>::XXX(int val) { /* code * }
```

but what I really want to do is specialize the XXX function based not on a particular
type for T but based on a particular type requirement for T, such as that T should be
copy_constructible, as an example. I am aware of how std::enable_if works but can
not come up with the correct C++ syantax to do what I want. Please note that I know
a technique that would enable me to partially specialize the class template itself for T
being copy-constructible, but I do not want to do that.

Comment: so basically you're asking how to use `std::enable_if`(in c++11)?

Comment: Functions cannot be partially specialized, in C++. You have to partially specialize the class. Depending on the precise circumstances you can typically find some work-around to specialized the template class, like using a helper class to implement the class method, and partially-specializing the helper class.

Comment: By the way, your example you're specializing the class, not the function.

Comment: Note that with C++20 concepts, I think you can easily _overload_ the function regarding `T` is copy constructible or not.

Comment: Enlico, the code above specializes a member function of the class template.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot partially specialize a function, but you can partially specialize a whole class:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename /* placeholder so there is a place for SFINAE */ = void>
class AAA
{
    void XXX(T val) { /* code */ }
    void YYY(T val) { /* code */ }
};

template<typename T>
class AAA<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>>>
{
    void XXX(T val) { /* code when T is copy constructible */ }
    void YYY(T val) { /* code when T is copy constructible */ }
};
```

Comment: Note that `std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>` is only available in C++17. In C++11, you should use `std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value`. The same apply for `std::enable_if_t`.

Comment: I know that I can partially specialize the whole class but wanted to avoid it for a certain reason. This does seem like a flaw in C++11, that I can only specialize a function of a class template based on an actual type for a parameter and not on some requirement of that type. I understand that C++20 offers a way to do what I want, so I will investigate that. Yes, I do know Jerome about what you mention, thanks !